# ansible file and directory permissions

Tags: linux, ansible

Trying to get ansible file/directory permissions to work.

In ansible I create a user:

```
user: name=testuser shell=/sbin/nologin uid=1234 comment="Test User"
```

Then I try to change ownership of a file directory:

```
file: path=/etc/myfile state=directory owner=testuser group=testuser mode=0644 recurse=yes
```

I also have tried setting a facl for a file:

```
acl:
     name: /var/log/audit/audit.log
     entity: filebeat
     etype: user
     permissions: rx
     state: present
```

When observing the file permissions and the facl, they appear to be set correctly.  However if I change the shell of my test user and login, I discover that I don't actually have the permissions that ansible presumably set.  I keep getting a "Permission Denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you get "Permission denied" when you try accessing to the directory content, e.g. running `ls -l /etc/myfile` .
This is the right *nix behaviour because you setted acces permission to `mode=0644`.

About directories, the execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside.

So, to allow your testuser going through the directory, set at least `mode=0744`.

To allow testuser group `mode=0754` and to allow everybody `mode=0755`

Comment: I also get permissions denied when trying to open the file directly (effectively reading it) which I don't think is explained by your answer...

Comment: What does it mean "open the file directly"? Is the file inside the directory? Did you try to set execution permission to the directory (chmod +x /etc/myfile)?

Comment: I don't need execution bit to simply open a file with an editor like vim...

Comment: You need execution bit on the directory containing the file you are going to open, even with vim. "vim /etc/mydir/file1" gets "Permission denied" if /etc/mydir has not execution bit for the user running vim, even if directory and file owner are your user.  Anyway, good luck.